# Autonumber in MS Access based on other fields

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to use auto-number function but it should depend on other fields. For example, I am creating vendor number (`XXXXXXX-XX`) based on the following:

1. First two digits: Country.
2. Digits 3 and 4: Province.
3. Digits 5, 6 and 7 : Unique number (Autogenerated).
4. Last two digits (after `-`): Number of branches.

Comment: Can dynamically build this reference when needed with expression in query or textbox using autonumber field for the Autogenerated part. Unless this value must be sequential with no gaps. Generating custom unique identifier is a common topic.

Comment: Use a combination of `Nz` and `DMax` to generate the unique number part as required. Autonumbers should only really be used as a means of relating data, and should have no meaning to the user.